# Is the space $B([a,b])$ separable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $a$, $b$ be two real numbers such that $a < b$, and let $B([a,b])$ denote the metric space consisting of all (real or complex-valued) functions $x=x(t)$, $y=y(t)$ that are bounded on the closed interval $[a,b]$ with the metric $d$ defined as follows: 
$$ d(x,y) \colon= \sup_{a\leq t \leq b} \ |x(t) - y(t)|.$$

Then how to determine whether or not this space is separable?

By definition, a metric space $X$ is said to be separable if it has a countable dense subset, that is, if there is a countable subset $M$ of $X$ such that $\bar{M} = X$.

Comment: That would be so kind of you!

Comment: Saaqib Mahmood, Thank you very much for posting this question. :)

Comment: @Edi you're welcome. In which context have you found this post to be so useful? Are you a math undergrad student?

Comment: I've switched from Chemistry to Math and I am learning as much materials I can catch. I didn't expect that B([a,b]) is not separable while C([a,b]) is!

Comment: @Edi I wish you best of luck in your journey through mathematics and hope you're liking it.

Comment: Thank you and best of luck to you too :)

Answer (score 11):

The space in question is **not** separable, because you do not have any continuity assumption on the elements. For example, $C([a,b])$ **is** separable.

To see that your space is not separable, it suffices to construct an uncountable family $(f_i)_i$ in $B([a,b])$ such that $d(f_i, f_j) \geq 1$ for all $i \neq j$ (**show this!!**, let $(g_n)_n$ be dense in $B([a,b])$, take $\varepsilon = 1/2$ and note that for each $i$ there is some $n_i$ such that $d(f_i, g_{n_i}) < 1/2$. Why does this help you?).

To construct such a family, think for a few minutes or consider the spoiler below.

> $$f_{x}\left(y\right)=\delta_{x,y}=\begin{cases}1, & x=y\\0, & x\neq y\end{cases} \text{ for each } x\in[a,b].$$

I leave it to you to check that actually $d(f_x, f_y) = 1$ holds for all $x \neq y$.

Comment: Phoemuex, how to show that the space $C[a,b]$ IS separable?

Comment: One possibility is to first note that the space of polynomials is dense in $C([a,b])$ (by a theorem of (Stone) Weierstraß). Then observe that each polynomial $p = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ can be approximated (uniformly on $[a,b]$) by $\sum_{i=0}^n b_i x^i$ with $b_i \in \Bbb{Q}$. Hence, the **countable** set of polynomials with rational coefficients is dense in $C([a,b])$.

Comment: Fine. Still my notes ask to prove that space it's separable.

Comment: Which one, $C([a,b])$ or $B([a,b])$? In the first case, see the proof sketch in the comment above (or do you have questions?). In the second case, you can not prove it, because it is **not** separable, as my answer above shows (or do you have questions?)

Comment: $B([a,b])$, surely it's a typo.

Comment: We could finalise the proof by observing that for $x\neq y$  we have that$f_x$ and $f_y$ are distance $1$ apart. Then pick for each $x \in [a,b]$ the function $f_x \in B([a,b]) $, and use it as the centre of an open ball of radius $1/2$. There are uncountably many non-intersecting balls since the the interval $[a,b]$ is uncountable. Suppose now that the set $D$ is dense in $B([a,b])$. Then since $D$ is dense each open ball must contain an element of $D$, but there are uncountably many balls, hence $D$ must be uncountable. Since any dense subset is uncountable $B([a,b])$ is not separable.